# Deserialize Json Object in c# windows phone 8

Tags: c#, json

I have the following JSON:

"{\"DDlState\":[{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"0\",\"State\":\"\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"0\",\"State\":\"All\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"1\",\"State\":\"JAMMU AND KASHMIR\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"2\",\"State\":\"PUNJAB\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"3\",\"State\":\"HIMACHAL PRADESH\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"4\",\"State\":\"HARYANA\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"5\",\"State\":\"DELHI\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"6\",\"State\":\"UTTAR PRADESH\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"7\",\"State\":\"BIHAR\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"8\",\"State\":\"WEST BENGAL\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"9\",\"State\":\"ORISSA\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"10\",\"State\":\"JHARKHAND\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"11\",\"State\":\"UTTARANCHAL\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"12\",\"State\":\"CHATTISGARH\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"13\",\"State\":\"CHANDIGARH\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"14\",\"State\":\"RAJASTHAN\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"15\",\"State\":\"MADHYA PRADESH\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"16\",\"State\":\"GUJARAT\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"17\",\"State\":\"MAHARASHTRA\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"18\",\"State\":\"GOA\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"19\",\"State\":\"KARNATAKA\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"20\",\"State\":\"KERALA\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"21\",\"State\":\"TAMIL NADU\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"22\",\"State\":\"ANDHRA PRADESH\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"23\",\"State\":\"MANIPUR\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"24\",\"State\":\"MIZORAM\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"25\",\"State\":\"NAGALAND\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"26\",\"State\":\"ASSAM\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"27\",\"State\":\"ARUNACHAL PRADESH\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"28\",\"State\":\"TRIPURA\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"29\",\"State\":\"MEGHALAYA\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"30\",\"State\":\"PONDICHERRY\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"31\",\"State\":\"UTRAKHAND\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"32\",\"State\":\"ONSITE\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"33\",\"State\":\"LAKSHADWEEP \"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"34\",\"State\":\"ANDAMAN AND NICOBAR ISLANDS \"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"35\",\"State\":\"DADRA AND NAGAR HAVELI\"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"36\",\"State\":\"DAMAN AND DIU \"},{\"respcode\":0,\"Id\":\"38\",\"State\":\"TELANGANA\"}],\"respcode\":0}"

And my code is:

```
        string JsonStr = e.Result.ToString();

        var container = DeserializeFromJson<DataJsonAttributeContainer>(JsonStr);
        MessageBox.Show(container.DDIState.Count.ToString()); // Prints 2
        MessageBox.Show(container.DDIState[0].State.Length.ToString()); // Prints 3
        //MessageBox.Show(container.attributes.Count.ToString()); // Prints 2
        //MessageBox.Show(container.attributes[0].State.Length.ToString()); // Prints 3

    }

    public static T DeserializeFromJson<T>(string json)
    {
        T deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
        return deserializedProduct;
    }

    public class Attributes
    {
        public string respcode { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
    }


    public class DataJsonAttributeContainer
    {
        public List<Attributes> DDIState { get; set; }
    }
```

But I am not able to deserialize JSON object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typo in property name of class `DataJsonAttributeContainer`. Attribute in JSON is named `DDlState` but in your class is named `DDIState` (`I`-> `l`).

Comment: I can't understand. Can you explain little bit more Plz.

Comment: Correct class by JSON is `public class DataJsonAttributeContainer { public List<Attributes> DDlState { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: Got that. Work fine and thanks